# "RobolectricTestRunner.class" not recognized in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use Robolectric to run unit tests but the Android Studio is not recognizing the class on:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
```

Details:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

And I'm importing dependency:

```
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.5.1"
```

And:

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}
```

It simply does not appear option to import the class.
Should I add any more dependencies I'm forgetting?

Error:

```
 error: package org.robolectric does not exist
 error: package org.robolectric does not exist
 error: package org.robolectric.shadows does not exist
 error: cannot find symbol class RobolectricTestRunner
 error: cannot find symbol variable Robolectric
 error: cannot find symbol variable ShadowApplication
```

Comment: can you try with testImplementation instead of testCompile. It's depracated now with gradle version 4

Comment: @Fakher the error is the same with androidTestImplementation and not recognizing with testImplementation. I use the: androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1' and it works correctly on the same project, just the roboletric that is not working.

Comment: Robolectric is always `test` and not `androidTest` dependency

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I solved the issue just by putting the test class inside the `src \ test` folder instead of putting it in the`src \ androidTest` folder

Comment: dude... you save life

Comment: @JacktheRipper LOL, glad to have helped!!

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot. But why does that happen? Is there a way to configure it to accept src \ androidTest?

Comment: Nice!! It helps!!

Comment: It took me 1 hour to solve the issue until I found your answer, thank you.

Comment: Since this helped me as well - you can get it to wotk in androidTest by using `androidTestImplementation` instead of `testImplementation` in gradle.

Answer (score 12):

Usually there will be 2 kinds of tests 'androidTest' and 'test'.

If you add dependency like `androidTestImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1'`, Robolectric package will only be imported in 'androidTest' classes.

If you add dependency like `testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1'`, they can only be imported in 'test' classes.

Comment: I just added both, androidTestImplementation and testImplementation

Comment: This is the right answer I must say

Answer (score 10):

I followed most of the recommendations without any luck.
I then changed a dot (.) to double-colon (::)

was ...

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
```

changed to ...

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
```

Answer (score 7):

`RobolectricGradleTestRunner` is deprecated since version 3 of Robolectric. Just use `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`
Take a look at official [documentation](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/).

Comment: I followed the official documentation, but the error continued ...
Any other suggestions?
Some more dependence, I don't know ...

Answer (score 2):

If your test file is written in kotlin then use @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)

Answer (score 0):

I have to move (downgrade) the version from 4.13.2 to 3.3.2